# Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /cart/Exception Value: User has no customer

Tags: python, django

**Error message**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/

Django Version: 3.2.7
Python Version: 3.8.10

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akshay/Django/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/akshay/Django/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/akshay/Django/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/akshay/Django/Frooty/myapp/views.py", line 61, in add_cart
    customer = request.user.customer
  File "/home/akshay/Django/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 247, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
  File "/home/akshay/Django/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 421, in __get__
    raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(

Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /cart/
Exception Value: User has no customer.
```

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,User


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'm finding a way to make the cart function work but can't able to figure out what the problem is. I use **django** authentication system with `AbsractUser` map this to customer `model.can`.

Comment: Based on the error message, I would surmise this statement ```customer = request.user.customer``` should be rewritten as ```customer = request.customer.user```

Comment: i think the error is clear.because the cureent user does not have a customer created for him.try to create a customer for that user then i think it should work

Comment: At what time do you link an `authenticated user` with a customer ? Because in the code above, there is no check on the `request.user` instance. As your define the `user` attribute in the `Customer` class as nullable. Try to check first if the user who make the request has a `customer` instance linked to it.

Comment: I review all your suggestions and I just discovered that the issue itself on the current user has logged in.The current user doesn't have a customer created for him,  When I change to superuser the error goes away.Thanks for the help.